# How to save mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel into HDFS?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I want to save my model of training in HDFS, I tried by:

```
model.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/tmp/Project/Model")
```

and

```
model.saveAsTextFile("hdfs:///sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/tmp/Project/Model")
```

But it dispaly an error is the following:

```
value saveAsTextFile is not a member of org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel
```

Can I use `saveAsnewAPIHadoopFile("hdfs://....")` ?

Can you tell how to save the model into HDFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [the scaladoc of MatrixFactorizationModel](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel) I could only find the method:

```
save(sc: SparkContext, path: String): Unit
```

Use `save` instead.

> **save(sc: SparkContext, path: String): Unit**
>
> Save this model to the given path.
>
> This saves:
>
> - human-readable (JSON) model metadata to path/metadata/
> - Parquet formatted data to path/data/

---

You seem to have used ALS. If so, please consider using `org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation` package (not `org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation`).

Comment: Yeah exactly, I used org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation. What is the difference when i use the ml and if i use mllib. Because in cases it should uses the mllib.